# Highlighting the current page link

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have built this website so far in Wordpress. 
[image]

I created the navigation links on the left manually by entering this code in the Wordpress Left Sidebar widget:

```
<ul>
<li><h5><a class="page page-id-35 page-template-default logged-in admin-bar no-customize-support tc-fade-hover-links tc-l-sidebar tc-sticky-header sticky-disabled tc-transparent-on-scroll no-navbar skin-green tc-side-menu tc-sticky-footer sn-right" href="?page_id=35/" >This is page 1</a></h5></li>

<li><h5><a class="page page-id-39 page-template-default logged-in admin-bar no-customize-support tc-fade-hover-links tc-l-sidebar tc-sticky-header sticky-disabled tc-transparent-on-scroll no-navbar skin-green tc-side-menu tc-sticky-footer sn-right" href="?page_id=39/">This is page 2</a></h5></li>
</ul>
```

The long class names that you see there I got them by looking at the source code for each of the two pages.

Then, in the CSS stylesheet, I added this:

```
.page.page-id-35.page-template-default.logged-in.admin-bar.no-customize-support.tc-fade-hover-links.tc-l-sidebar.tc-sticky-header.sticky-disabled.tc-transparent-on-scroll.no-navbar.skin-green.tc-side-menu.tc-sticky-footer.sn-right a.page.page-id-35.page-template-default.logged-in.admin-bar.no-customize-support.tc-fade-hover-links.tc-l-sidebar.tc-sticky-header.sticky-disabled.tc-transparent-on-scroll.no-navbar.skin-green.tc-side-menu.tc-sticky-footer.sn-right,
.page.page-id-39.page-template-default.logged-in.admin-bar.no-customize-support.tc-fade-hover-links.tc-l-sidebar.tc-sticky-header.sticky-disabled.tc-transparent-on-scroll.no-navbar.skin-green.tc-side-menu.tc-sticky-footer.sn-right a.page.page-id-39.page-template-default.logged-in.admin-bar.no-customize-support.tc-fade-hover-links.tc-l-sidebar.tc-sticky-header.sticky-disabled.tc-transparent-on-scroll.no-navbar.skin-green.tc-side-menu.tc-sticky-footer.sn-right 
{
  background:red;
  color:white;
}
```

I was expecting the links on the left to be highlighted when their corresponding page was loaded on the browser. The pages load fine, but there is no highlighting. Anyone knows what I am doing wrong? Or is there any other technique to highlight the navigation menu for the current page?

Comment: Hard to say without knowing how the links are generated. If you use the methods WordPress provides these links automatically get the classes `current_page_ancestor` and `current_page`, which you can easily use to style them. However, these classes seem to be missing in your case. This is most probably something that is missing in your theme.

Comment: You are missing class of current active page I think.

Comment: With WordPress custom menus, the class `.current-menu-item` is automatically added to the active link. Much better than coding it yourself.

Adding a custom menu area isn't too scary - https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/add-menus-to-wordpress/

Comment: @GeraldSchneider I myself generated the links on the sidebar by manually typing a list of hrefs inside a Text element which I added to the Left Sidebar widget.

Comment: @HelpingHands, true. I was editing my answer meanwhile and added the classes, but still the same.